# isCellEditable is not working is Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to edit a particular cell so I edit the `isCellEditable` method after this when I call the `isCellEditable` component it goes with the edit value true but it does not edit that particular. Please help me out. As is passes the row value and column value as 0 and 0. What should I do to make the particular cell editable?

```
package javaapplication2;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Himanshu
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public boolean edit = false;
    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(3, 1));

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                if(edit == true){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    );
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    jPanel1.add(jScrollPane1);

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(jButton2);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(jButton1);

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab1", jPanel1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 771, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 432, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        NewJFrame n = new NewJFrame();
        n.initial();
    }
    public void initial(){

       // String [][] data = new String[][]{{"1","2","3","4"},{"1","2","3","4"},{"1","2","3","4"  }};
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        edit = true;
        model.isCellEditable(0, 0);

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this

```
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final NewJFrame frame = new NewJFrame();
            frame.initial();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
/*        NewJFrame n = new NewJFrame();
        n.initial();*/ // delete the commented code
```

Your previous code  new two frames, one editable but not visible `n` , one visible but not editable .

---

For only (0,0) is editable, The call of `isCellEditable` method is no use, it is pure without side effects and it just returns a boolean value.

You could change the implementation of your `isCellEditable` method to

```
 public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
 return edit && (rowIndex == 0 && columnIndex == 0);
 }
```

---

Of course, you  can always choose not to hardcode numbers, and write a method such as `setEditableCell` and changes to `return edit && (rowIndex == rowNum && columnIndex == columnNum)`;

Comment: Thanks @aristotll. But one more question when i am passing (0,0) in cell editable function but it making all cells editable rather than particular cell. can you please help into it?

Comment: Thanks a lot@aristotll . Got it now